# How to write a testbench to loop through 4 inputs?

Tags: loops, testing, verilog, system-verilog

I have to create the Verilog code and testbench for this schematic.

[image: problem]

I have the design for it here.

```
module prob1(input wire a,b,c,d, output wire out);
    assign out = (a||d)&&(!d&&b&&c);
endmodule
```

Here is what I have for the testbench so far.

```
module prob1_tb();
    reg a,b,c,d;
    wire out;

    prob1 prob1_test(a,b,c,d, out);

    initial begin
        for(int i=0; i=16; i=i+1)
            <loop code here>
        end
    end
endmodule
```

The part I am having issue with is how can I convert that number into those 4 inputs that are being used in the schematic? Or is there a better way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple way using the concatenation operator:

```
module prob1(input wire a,b,c,d, output wire out);
    assign out = (a||d)&&(!d&&b&&c);
endmodule

module prob1_tb();
    reg a,b,c,d;
    wire out;

    prob1 prob1_test(a,b,c,d, out);

    initial begin
        $monitor(a,b,c,d,out);
        for (int i=0; i<16; i=i+1) begin
            {a,b,c,d} = i;
            #1;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Output:

```
00000
00010
00100
00110
01000
01010
01100
01110
10000
10010
10100
10110
11000
11010
11101
11110
```

Yes, there are better ways to verify logic.  The first thing to do is to introduce random values (refer to the `$urandom` functions in the IEEE Std 1800-2009).  Of course, you also need to perform checks of your output using a model, which in your case is trivial.

Depending on how much time (and training) you have, you could adopt a standard flow, such as the Universal Verification Methodology (UVM).  People build careers around verification.